# Skype keeps crashing when trying to write a message

Tags: windows, crash, skype

Skype keeps crashing when I open it and try to write a message.

It's been getting progressively worse within the past hour. At first it would just crash randomly, but now I just can't send messages, and very rarely I can send a couple of messages.

These are the details of the crash:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: Skype.exe
  Application Version:  5.5.0.124
  Application Timestamp:    4e96a02b
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17651
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4e211319
  Exception Code:   0eedfade
  Exception Offset: 0000b9bc
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: cae9
  Additional Information 2: cae9a046c78e126365608eedf36aac5c
  Additional Information 3: 86f6
  Additional Information 4: 86f6c37b0a43e0602f713cc9bec72601
```

Comment: Uninstall Skype, restart the computer, download Skype and install again?

Comment: skype sucks now a days... just use Google talk...

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I looked to check if the Skype servers were having issues, when I found this post:

http://heartbeat.skype.com/2011/12/skype_for_windows_crashing_on.html

Installing the [5.7 beta](http://www.skype.com/go/download-beta) fixed the problem for me! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, and I still do. I tried unistalling, rebooting, and reinstaling Skype.  That did not fix it.

What I was able to determine was that it is local to the account I was using. I logged in as a different user, on the same Win 7 Laptop, installed Skype V 5.5.59.124 and it worked fine.

This is perplexing.  I think it must be something in the the profile, and I'm running a deep scan now.